# Application's package can't find in Device?

Tags: android, package

I've successfully written a simple android database application, but I can't see and find my package on the device.

When, I'm using this application on my Device it doesn't show the database in my device's file manager.

What am I doing wrong? Also, what do I need to do to display my package on my device? Is there any

permission I'm missing?

Comment: @Pinki: yes, i'm using that. <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple to open database in android device . Just copy it from data/data directory to sdcard using code and then copy from sdcard to PC manually.

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer through Chat room.

Answer (score 0):

The database that an application creates is private to the application and cannot be seen from another application.